# Search OneDrive files by title only with Microsoft Graph APIs

Tags: java, android, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The below code searches OneDrive using Microsoft Graph APIs.

```
List<DriveItem> items = graphServiceClient
    .getMe()
    .getDrive()
    .getRoot()
    .getSearch("abc")
    .buildRequest()
    .get().getCurrentPage();
```

This codes returns all files and folders that matches the title (and probably content also as per the documentation) "abc".

How can I restrict search results to fetch only the files that matched the title "abc"?

**Edit**

Please vote for this feature request at-

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16855591-microsoft-graph-api-search-onedrive-files-by-titl

Comment: why this feature request is deleted?

Comment: I haven't done that. No idea; it was a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to restrict the search target to just the title at this point. At this time, you'll need to perform client-side filtering of the results. Please open a feature request at the [Office Developer Platform UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) page. Link to it from this post so other people can find and up vote it.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Done! https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16855591-microsoft-graph-api-search-onedrive-files-by-titl